# More on shadows of 3D convex bodies

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Ref: [Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402665/shadows-and-planar-sections-of-polyhedra)

By shadow we mean the orthogonal projection of a convex 3D body C onto a 2D plane, for example, the shadow on the xy-plane, with C above (z>0) that plane and the light at L=(0,0,+∞). C an be freely rotated as it hovers above the xy-plane. Are the following claims easy to prove/counter?

1. If a convex 3D body C has all its shadows (orthogonal projected onto any plane) to be of equal area, then, C is a sphere.
2. If a convex 3D body C has all its shadows to be of equal perimeter, then, C is a sphere.

Note added on 6th August 2023: This question has been answered in comments below.

Comment: your question #1 seems to be a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138525/a-question-about3-3-dimensional-convex-bodies/138534

Comment: and @alvarezpaiva's comment on my answer to that question should give you a good hint for question #2, if you replace the square of the radial function by the support function

Comment: Thank you for those pointers. I guess, despite the repetition, this post adds a little bit of value in the second claim (if you think otherwise, do comment). A further claim has also been posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450310/a-claim-on-planar-sections-of-3d-convex-bodies

Comment: you're welcome. Feel free to write up an answer to #2 if you think it adds value

Comment: As given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(geometry), the girth of a geometric object, in a certain direction, is the perimeter of its parallel projection in that direction (perimeter of the shadow).

From Hilbert and Cohn-Vossen's 'Geometry and the Imagination', page 216-7, Minkowski has proved that all convex surfaces of constant girth (ie. all its shadows have constant perimeter), then the surface is one of constant width - not necessarily a sphere. This answers question 2.

Comment: In above, 'girth' should be viewed not merely as parallel projection but *orthogonal projection*. The argument remains valid.