# Convex 3d bodies for which all planar sections with max diameter have same diameter

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

Ref:
1.
[A claim on planar sections of 3D convex bodies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450310/a-claim-on-planar-sections-of-3d-convex-bodies)

2. [On convex 3d bodies whose shadows are all of constant diameter](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452257/on-convex-3d-bodies-whose-shadows-are-all-of-constant-diameter)

Given a 3D convex body $C$ and a specified direction $n$, we consider the planar sections of $C$ normal to $n$ with (1) maximum diameter and (2) maximum least width.

- How does one characterize those convex bodies for which for every $n$, the diameter of the corresponding max diameter section is the same?

(Following a comment in ref 2 above from Yoav Kallus, an oblate spheroid is an example of such a body as are bodies of constant width).

- Same question as above with maximum least width replacing of max diameter.
  (a prolate spheroid is an example of such a body).
- What about bodies for which for every $n$, the ratio between the diameter of the max diameter section and least width of the max least width section (or the maximum from among sections normal to $n$ of the ratio between diameter and least width)  is a constant?